# Retrieving MinGW32 for Ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu, github, mingw

ALL,

I am trying to reproduce an environment from GitHub docker container.

It has Ubuntu, wine and (based on the configure input) x86_64-w64-mingw32.

However, it looks like this compiler is not available for Ubuntu 20.

I need to investigate a build failure so need to reproduce the environment.

Or if someone can help with retrieving the container and running it locally or maybe even getting access to the container on GitHub - it would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what problems you are having or even what you tried. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] in case you haven't already.

Comment: @UlrichEckhard, my understanding is that only MinGW64 is available in the Ubuntu repo. So if I can get MinGW32 installed or get access/download the build machine on github it would be great. This is my question/problem.